# GKSession - kill and renew session

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gksession

In order to read a new display name of a peer I need to kill and renew the GKSession. Setting it to nil and initiate it anew does not work. In the code below, the NSLog in the *for-loop* to show the available peers is not called (there's no error message):

```
-(IBAction) btnRefresh:(id) sender {

    self.currentSession = nil;

    self.currentSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"anything" displayName:name sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
    self.currentSession.delegate = self;
    self.currentSession.available = YES;
    self.currentSession.disconnectTimeout = 0;
    [self.currentSession setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];

    peerListAvailable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[currentSession peersWithConnectionState:GKPeerStateAvailable]];

    for (NSString *peer in peerListAvailable) {
       NSLog(@"found available peer; checking name and ID... %@, %@",[currentSession displayNameForPeer:peer], peer);
    }
```

What is wrong with setting the currentSession to nil and initiate it anew? 
Maybe you know of another way to renew a GKSession?
Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The following methods illustrate `GKSession` setup and teardown:

```
- (void)setupSession
{
    gkSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
    gkSession.delegate = self;
    gkSession.disconnectTimeout = 5;
    gkSession.available = YES;
}

- (void)teardownSession
{
    gkSession.available = NO;
    [gkSession disconnectFromAllPeers];
}
```

If you're interested in delving deeper, take a look at [GKSessionP2P](https://github.com/shrtlist/GKSessionP2P), a demo app that illustrates the ad-hoc networking features of `GKSession`. The app both advertises itself on the local network and automatically connects to available peers, establishing a peer-to-peer network.